# Laravel Task Scheduling being executed every minute for no reason

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have setup a command that has to be run once at the last day of the month. This is how I've done it:

```
$schedule->command('report:send')->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

Today is the last day of the month so it works great. But the thing is this command is being executed every minute. So every minute I get an email in my inbox :/

Is it possible that this is maybe happening because I used `->everyMinute();` while testing and the setting has to be refreshed or something?

Comment: Have you tried further limiting the callback, like only execute when the time is 11:22?

Comment: @sisve No I did not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command will be tested every time the cron start. I believe your cron is executed every minutes and because of the command return true for this day, it will be exectued every minutes.

What you can do is :

```
$schedule->command('report:send')->daily()->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

or

```
$schedule->command('report:send')->dailyAt('13:00')->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

Comment: Hmm it's currently 08:50 my local time and I've set it at `->dailyAt('08:48')` but nothing happens?

Comment: Probably some issues with my server time I'll check my server time and change it acordingly

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this:

```
$schedule->command('report:send')->monthly()->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

Hope this work for you